# What happens to a users questions and answer when they are removed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

When a user is removed are all of that user's questions and answers, and all answers to the user's questions, also removed?

Comment: No. They remain with the author's name given as "userxxxxx". You can tell that the user was removed because userxxxxx is not a hyperlink. E.g., second answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/downvoting-because-of-duplication)

Comment: @LVK: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the "not a hyperlink" situation also happens with content migrated from other stackexchange sites.

Comment: @tomasz You are right; in both cases the lack of hyperlink shows the lack of MSE account.

Comment: +1 for the wonderful example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends. There are two forms of removal:

- Deletion deletes all posts with a negative vote total. On posts with a non-negative vote total, it denormalizes identity (as in LVK's comment).
- Destruction deletes all content, but it is only usable on users with less than 500 reputation. This is reserved for spammers, etc.