# About the message "User was removed"

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, users, reputation-tab

Sometimes (rarely) the message "User was removed" appears. I read the given explanation:

> This message means that a user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted (either by request or due to violating the network's terms of service). As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you gained or lost from them was undone. The resultant reputation change could be any amount; it could even be a reputation gain if enough of the removed votes were downvotes. All the reputation changes from a single user's deletion are rolled into a single event in the reputation page labelled "User was removed"... etc.

OK. I agree with this. But it isn't my concern.

In fact, it doesn't matter who is the removed user. I suppose that, not only his question is removed, but also all the answers from other users. Is it true?

My question is : When the message "User was removed" appears, how can we know what was the subject deleted and what answer from me was deleted as well?

For example :

[image]

How can I know the topic of the removed question? How can I know which one of my various answers was removed accordingly?

Comment: This is about one part of your question: [What happens to a users questions and answer when they are removed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6182)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: That other question seems to be Michael Hardys however.

Comment: I believe that even if the user is suspended you get the same message (User was removed). Maybe someone can confirm that ?

Comment: BTW since you are above 10k, you can [find your deleted posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948#13949). If you have some answers which were deleted together with the question, you can simply look at your reputation tab what message appeared there when the question was deleted.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak : Thanks you very much for your answer. I looked at my reputation tab and saw the day when the question was deleted. But this provides no clue to find what is the topic of the deleted message. I also tried a search with deleted:1 . This gave no result related with the present problem. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There just is no answer that was deleted. Note what it says (added emphasis): "This message means that a user who **voted** for one of your posts had their account deleted[...]"

What happened is that a user was removed that had cast an upvote on one of your answers, and the ten points gained from that upvote were removed (to be precise, it could also be any other combination of votes that leads to +10).

Since votes are generally anonymous, one is not told which particular vote; but there is also not much actual need to know this, especially as the removal does not affect the visible score of the post.

Usually, posts created by a user that has their account deleted are in fact not deleted. There are only some circumstances in which they are deleted; details can be found in the post linked to by Martin: [What happens to a users questions and answer when they are removed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6182/what-happens-to-a-users-questions-and-answer-when-they-are-removed)

Yet, anyway, this is not what caused your reputation change. If the reputation change is due to a post-deletion as a consequence of a user deletion, it will show up as any other reputation change due to a post deletion, that is, it will say "removed" and then specify the post that was removed.

**To sum up,** the points are lost because the effect of votes got removed, not because a post got removed. None of your posts is directly affected by this event.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. Probably you are right. My question was not about the reputation change : +10 or -10 doesn't matter. I am just curious to known to which one among my answers this event is related, even if the answer is not removed. So, I understand that it is not possible to know. Finally this is not really important.