# How can I lose today $176$ reputation points?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, deleted-accounts

*This is probably a silly question.*

Looking at my reputation points five minutes ago, I notice that I lost $176$ reputation points because *user was removed*.

Is there a way to know and see the list of questions which suffered of this user removal ?

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with the ["*Screw this site. I am leaving.*"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28779/291201) user, now only known as `user223391`.

Comment: How do you make the search ? I am totally ignorant in this are (plus many other). Thanks.

Comment: It was just a guess. I happened to notice the withdrawal notice, and my mixed bag of rep change,  within a short period of time, so Occam's razor said they could be related. Losing 6 downvotes and 14 upvotes (in my case) is not typical of the drive-by posters who change login at each question, and often get their accounts closed. I also don't understand why the big secrecy behind *which* user `was removed`.

Comment: Interesting question, I also got 2 upvotes and 1 downvote retracted, however only the -20 reputation appeared on the reputation feed the +2 I noticed from my total reputation

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26277/about-the-message-user-was-removed https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed

Comment: @dxiv If a user who has participated as much as that one, their votes are not automatically annulled. IIRC the SE staff needs to be involved in such a case. Don't remember the details. OTOH when a short-lived account is deleted, the votes go as well by default. FWIW I lost 95 points worth of upvotes and gained 2 points from a removed downvote.

Comment: Related posts on meta Stack Exchange: [How can I find posts related to lost reputation due to a “user was removed” message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126698)

Comment: If you downloaded your reputation breakdown from https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation at some point in the past you can download it again and compare the files. Other possibility is to use in some way [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). It is updated once a week - Monday 03:00 UTC. So at the moment all upvotes on your posts are still in the database. If you check the next week, you'll get results without the votes of this user. Somewhat related question on meta.MO: [Is it possible to know the list of removed users?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3629)

Comment: So, I should see myself as lucky, since I *only* lost $160$ reputation points…

Comment: Some related older posts on this meta: [Can I know where I lost my reputation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21831) and [Is it possible to know which posts were affected by user removal?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3857)

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly. If you are asking which of *your* posts  were affected, then it is a duplicate of [Can I know where I lost my reputation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21831) (OTOH if you want *all* posts affected by this, then this is a different question. Although I suppose that this information would be much more difficult to find - if at all possible.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak. Thank you very much. May I confess that I do not understand how people can cancel their account on this fantastic site ? Cheers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen do you know what the exact criteria are for determining whether a user's votes are preserved or not upon deletion of their account?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I'm afraid I do not know the details. The links [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20943/11619) should help.

Comment: how can I lose the moderator election this year? Being the candidate with lowest score and highest negative votes, I though I was a shoe in. _Now_, do you want to talk about some 176 points... mhh?

Comment: I lost 85. It did feel like a lot. I think removing votes on that order is a poor system. They should keep the votes unless there are <100 or so.